# Creating a for loop that creates a histogram for each column and groupsby index value

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby, histogram

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                        time_spent_inx            time_spent_iny
name      bin                                                     
team_a    (0, 200]                        10                     0
          (200, 400]                       0                     0
          (400, 600]                      20                     0
          (600, 800]                       0                    20
          (800, 1000]                     20                    20
          (1000, 1200]                    10                     0
team_b    (0, 200]                         5                    35
          (200, 400]                       0                     0
          (400, 600]                      40                     0
          (600, 800]                      10                    20
          (800, 1000]                     20                     0
          (1000, 1200]                    10                    70
team_c    (0, 200]                         5                    30
          (200, 400]                      25                     0
          (400, 600]                       0                     0
          (600, 800]                      10                     5
          (800, 1000]                      5                     0
          (1000, 1200]                    10                    25
```

**I want to create a histogram for each column, for each different team. The bins are already pre-defined.**

this is what I've tried to use so far:

```
df = df.reset_index()

a= df["bin"].astype(str)
b= df["time_spent_inx"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(100,100) )
ax.hist(a,6,weights=b, by = df["name"])
ax.set_xticklabels(a,rotation = 90)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', labelsize=60, width=2.5, length=10)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', labelsize=60, width=2.5, length=10)                       
plt.show()
```

I've used the weights argument since the data is already binned.  the above code is just i'ved tried to use to plot the histogram for one column ("time_spent_inx").

This is one error i get: AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'by'

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html
There isn't a 'by' paramter in matplotlib hist

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. As far as I can see you already calculated the bins. If you are happy using [plotly](https://plotly.com/) you could follow these steps

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': {0: 'team_a',
  1: 'team_a',
  2: 'team_a',
  3: 'team_a',
  4: 'team_a',
  5: 'team_a',
  6: 'team_b',
  7: 'team_b',
  8: 'team_b',
  9: 'team_b',
  10: 'team_b',
  11: 'team_b',
  12: 'team_c',
  13: 'team_c',
  14: 'team_c',
  15: 'team_c',
  16: 'team_c',
  17: 'team_c'},
 'bin': {0: '(0, 200]',
  1: '(200, 400]',
  2: '(400, 600]',
  3: '(600, 800]',
  4: '(800, 1000]',
  5: '(1000, 1200]',
  6: '(0, 200]',
  7: '(200, 400]',
  8: '(400, 600]',
  9: '(600, 800]',
  10: '(800, 1000]',
  11: '(1000, 1200]',
  12: '(0, 200]',
  13: '(200, 400]',
  14: '(400, 600]',
  15: '(600, 800]',
  16: '(800, 1000]',
  17: '(1000, 1200]'},
 'time_spent_inx': {0: 10,
  1: 0,
  2: 20,
  3: 0,
  4: 20,
  5: 10,
  6: 5,
  7: 0,
  8: 40,
  9: 10,
  10: 20,
  11: 10,
  12: 5,
  13: 25,
  14: 0,
  15: 10,
  16: 5,
  17: 10},
 'time_spent_iny': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 20,
  4: 20,
  5: 0,
  6: 35,
  7: 0,
  8: 0,
  9: 20,
  10: 0,
  11: 70,
  12: 30,
  13: 0,
  14: 0,
  15: 5,
  16: 0,
  17: 25}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Transform wide df to long one

```py
df_long = pd.melt(df, 
                  id_vars=['name', 'bin'],
                  value_vars=["time_spent_inx", "time_spent_iny"],
                  var_name="time_spent")
```

## Use plotly express

```py
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(df_long, 
       x="bin", 
       y="value", 
       color="name", 
       barmode="group", 
       facet_col="time_spent")
```

[image]